# Is there a way to get the inputted number aside from the Gather request?

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to get the inputted number aside from the Gather request?

Like, are they stored somewhere we can query later via the call id?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Assuming that you mean you are looking for a way to get numbers entered into the phone's keypad during a call, then no, the only way in a Twilio call to get those digits is via the callback after using [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather).

If you want to store those `Digits` you could put them into a database, keyed with the `CallSid` that you receive as a parameter with every webhook too, so that you can retrieve them later.

If you are looking for the number that was dialled, that should come through as the `To` parameter in every [TwiML request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request).